# Laravel testing POST JSON

Tags: laravel

I am writing test in `laravel`. I want o send `JSON` in post. Below is the image

[image]

How can i send the `json` data in `postJson` ?

```
/**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_create_attribute()
    {
        $response =  $this->postJson('/api/catalog/attributes?storeId=1000000006', How to send json data);

        $response->assertStatus(201);
    }
```

Comment: Please take a look at the HTTP Tests documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-tests

Answer (score 1):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
 
$response = Http::post('http://example.com/users', [
    'name' => 'Steve',
    'role' => 'Network Administrator',
]);
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client

Comment: where is json data?

Comment: 'name' & 'role' is data

Comment: $response will have `assertStatus` method ?

Comment: and i want to send json data

Comment: I am writing test not calling API...

Comment: You need to read this https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-tests

Comment: I have already read this not found any solution

Comment: if I understand you correctly, then you want to receive code 201 when answering Json